# CERT.RSA is missing in debug build APK file after upgrade AndroidStuio and Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

After upgrading AndroidStudio to 3.5 and Gradle to 3.5.0(gradle-5.4.1), when launching the app directly from AndroidStudio, the installed APK does not contain the signature file CERT.RSA in META-INF folder. Our code will check this file for anti-crack purpose. However, in the release build APK, the signature is fine.

Same code was working well on previous version of Android studio and gradle plugin. It seems that the new upgrade made this change to accelerate the debug process by eliminating some components/procedures which they believe is not necessary in debug build.

Does anyone have an idea how to tell AndroidStudio/Gradle to properly sign the APK just as the previous version did?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The CERT.RSA is only used in jar signing (a.k.a. v1 signing scheme). When using V2 signing scheme, the APK can be signed without this file to exist. This is a perfectly acceptable APK if your minSdkVersion is at least 24, so consider adjusting the "anti-crack" tool.

In the short term, you can also keep signing with v1 signing scheme by setting `v1SigningEnabled true` in your signingConfig block: https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig:v1SigningEnabled

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My minSdk is 17. But I guess the new AndroidStuio optimization for accelerating the debug process will try to detect my test device and will omit the V1 signing when it found an AndroidP device, right? Because I tried build->Build apks and the debug APK will contain the CERT.RSA, however, after a direct launching, the APK in the debug build folder does not contain the CERT.RSA file.

Comment: adding "v1SigningEnabled true" cannot force Android studio to apply v1 signing when directly launch the application. Anything else is missing?

Comment: Is the file missing also when you build the release build?

Comment: The file is only missing when launched directly from AndroidStudio (click run). If I chose to build the APK, both debug(build->build apk bundle/apk->build apk) and release(generate signed apk) build will contain the CERT.RSA file.

Comment: Yes, it's an optimization to make deployment to the device faster.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this optimization?

Comment: Why rely on this in the first place?

Comment: @Pierre, I only know this file contains some info that is related to my sign-key, which will change if some one modified my apk and sign it with another key. So it is easy for me to check if the apk is cracked. After migrating to V2, I don't which file I could rely on.